# Equivalent of @keyframes for jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm looking for a way to emulate the CSS @keyframes animations using jQuery.

I need to change the background image each **x** seconds following a list of images provided when the user moves mouse over an element.
The CSS animations should be:

```
.readon:hover {
    animation: readonin 2s;
}

@keyframes readonin {
     0% { background-image: url(1.png); }
    50% { background-image: url(2.png); }
   100% { background-image: url(3.png); }
}
```

I've found plugins like Spritely but they works with sprites and I need instead to change the image background of the element.
Use the set-interval function of Javascript seems a bad solution because I can't find a way to stop the animation when the user moves the mouse out of the element.

Comment: *"I can't find a way to stop the animation"* Erm... `clearInterval`?

Comment: No, he means that he can't stop the animation pure @keyframes is used.

Comment: mouseout event for the win!! http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like...

```
var images = ["1.png", "2.png", "3.png"];
var $element = $(".readon");
var interval = null;
$element.hover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var i = 0;
    var fn = function () {
        $this.css("background-image", "url(" + images[i] + ")");
        i = ++i % images.length;
    };
    interval = setInterval(fn, 666);
    fn();
},
function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
    $(this).css("background-image", "none");
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YKUYB/) of a similar concept (with background colours).

It should be clear enough to see what's going on. Basically we start looping over the images and setting them as the background image on mouse over, and reset it when the mouse leaves.

Comment: @FezVrasta Then call `clearInterval()` when `i == images.length - 1`.

Comment: There's a problem, sometimes the animation flicks, [example](http://jsfiddle.net/GbS7Y/1/), where's the problem?

Comment: @FezVrasta I can't see any flicker. Also, you'd be much better off using a sprite-sheet for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like [jQuery-Keyframes](https://github.com/krazyjakee/jQuery-Keyframes)
to generate new keyframes at runtime if that is what you are after.